# PhpStorm DQL and sprintf

Tags: php, phpstorm, dql

When I write a DQL query with PhpStorm's DQL language support, it highlights me the **%s** which I use for entity name substitution later via sprintf.

[image]

Is there a way to inject entity names into the DQL so that it wouldn't be treated as an error? I don't want to hardcode the class names neither I'm a big fan of concatenation in such statements.

Comment: i guess ... anyQL ... am stalking this question for my own edification and sanity :)

Comment: @YvesLeBorg not really, it works fine with pure SQL.

Comment: Check what you have at `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Tools | Database | User Parameters` -- may help (unless DQL plugin does not support such parameters yet; in such case consider creating new ticket -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=%23%7BPlugin:%20DQL%7D%20 )